# Optimizing Java Socket Sending Android to PC

Tags: java, android, sockets, optimization

I need Your help!

So I got this app on an Android device, in which I get data from the accelerometer, and button presses which get this data to an edittext, and sets listeners on the edittextes.

When it's changed, there's a functions that creates a socket, sends data, and closes the socket.

Then I have a server app on my computer, in which I create serversockets, and create two threads that are waiting for `serversocket.accept()` that gets the data and put it into texbox. Simple as that.

I'm glad that I got it working anyway :-) but the point is, it's not working so well. I believe that whole communication is bad and not optimized. It sends data well, but often freezes, then unfreezes and sends quickly all previous data and so on.

I'm sorry for my bad code, but can someone please take a good look on this, and propose what I should change and how I could make it work more smooth and stable? :-(

Here's the Client code:

```
package com.test.klienttcp;

//import's...

public class Klient extends Activity implements SensorListener {


final String log = "Log";
EditText textOut;
EditText adres;
EditText test;
EditText gazuje;
TextView textIn;
TextView tekst;
TextView dziala;
String numer = null;
float wspk = 0; // wspolczynniki kalibracji
float wychylenietmp = 0;
float wychylenie = 0;
int tmp = 0;
int i = 0;
boolean wysylaj = false;

SensorManager sm = null;


 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);

     textOut = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textout);
     adres = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.adres);
     gazuje = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.gazuje);
     Button kalibracja = (Button)findViewById(R.id.kalibracja);
     Button polacz = (Button)findViewById(R.id.polacz);
     Button gaz = (Button)findViewById(R.id.gaz);
     Button hamulec = (Button)findViewById(R.id.hamulec);
     kalibracja.setOnClickListener(kalibracjaOnClickListener);
     polacz.setOnClickListener(polaczOnClickListener);
     gaz.setOnTouchListener(gazOnTouchListener);
     hamulec.setOnTouchListener(hamulecOnTouchListener);
     sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

     //text listener steering
     textOut.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
         public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
         }
         public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
         }
         public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
             if(wysylaj)
             {
                 Wyslij();
             }
         }
     });

   //text listener for throttle         
   gazuje.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
         public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
         }
         public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
         }
         public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
             if(wysylaj)
             {
                 Gaz();
             }
         }
     });

 }

 Button.OnClickListener polaczOnClickListener
 = new Button.OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 if(wysylaj==false)
 {
     wysylaj = true;
 }
 else
 {
     wysylaj = false;
 }
}};

//throttle button handler
Button.OnTouchListener gazOnTouchListener
= new Button.OnTouchListener(){
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        gazuje.setText("1");
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        gazuje.setText("0");
    }
    return false;
}};

//brake button handler
Button.OnTouchListener hamulecOnTouchListener
= new Button.OnTouchListener(){
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        gazuje.setText("2");
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        gazuje.setText("0");
    }
    return false;
}};


 //sensor handler
 public void onSensorChanged(int sensor, float[] values) {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (sensor == SensorManager.SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER) {
                wychylenie = values[0] * 10;
                tmp = Math.round(wychylenie);
                wychylenie = tmp / 10;
                if(wychylenie != wychylenietmp)
                {
                textOut.setText(Float.toString(wychylenie - wspk));
                wychylenietmp = wychylenie;
                }
            }
        }
    }

 public void onAccuracyChanged(int sensor, int accuracy) {
        Log.d(log, "onAccuracyChanged: " + sensor + ", accuracy: " + accuracy);

    }

 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        sm.registerListener(this, SensorManager.SENSOR_ORIENTATION
                | SensorManager.SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        sm.unregisterListener(this);
        super.onStop();
    }

    //callibration handler

     Button.OnClickListener kalibracjaOnClickListener
     = new Button.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     try {
         wspk = wychylenie;
         } catch (Exception e)
         {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }};

    // sending steering data
    public void Wyslij()
    {
        Socket socket = null;
         DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
         DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;
         try {
             numer = adres.getText().toString();
             socket = new Socket(numer, 8888);
             dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
             dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
             dataOutputStream.writeUTF(textOut.getText().toString());
              if(socket.isClosed())
              {
                  test.setText("Socket zamkniety");
              }
          //textIn.setText(dataInputStream.readUTF());
         } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IOException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
         }
         finally{
              if (socket != null){
               try {
                socket.close();
               } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
               }
              }

              if (dataOutputStream != null){
               try {
                dataOutputStream.close();
               } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
               }
              }

              if (dataInputStream != null){
               try {
                dataInputStream.close();
               } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
               }
              }
             }

    }

    //sending throttle data
    public void Gaz()
    {
        Socket socket = null;
         DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
         DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;
         try {
             numer = adres.getText().toString();
             socket = new Socket(numer, 8889);
             dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
             dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
             dataOutputStream.writeUTF(gazuje.getText().toString());
              if(socket.isClosed())
              {
                  test.setText("Socket zamkniety");
              }
          //textIn.setText(dataInputStream.readUTF());
         } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IOException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
         }
         finally{
              if (socket != null){
               try {
                socket.close();
               } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
               }
              }

              if (dataOutputStream != null){
               try {
                dataOutputStream.close();
               } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
               }
              }

              if (dataInputStream != null){
               try {
                dataInputStream.close();
               } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
               }
              }
             }

    }

}
```

And here's Server code:

```
//import's...


public class Okno 
{
    public static float wychylenie;
    public static String gaz="0";
    public static float jedzie;
    public static int skrecam, gazuje;
    public static String wiadomosc="100";
    private static int maxConnections=0, port=8888, portg=8889;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        skrecam = 0;
        gazuje = 0;
        Window ok = new Window();
        ok.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
        ok.setVisible(true);
        ok.setResizable(false);
        ok.setTitle("Serwer TCP");

        int i=0;

        try{
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            Robot robotgaz = new Robot();
            ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(port);
            ServerSocket listenergaz = new ServerSocket(portg);

          while((i++ < maxConnections) || (maxConnections == 0)){

           //create thread for steering
            if(skrecam == 0)
            {
                skrecam=1;
            doComms conn_c= new doComms(listener);
            Thread t = new Thread(conn_c);
            t.start();
            }

            //create thread for throttle
            if(gazuje == 0)
            {
                gazuje=1;
            doCommsgaz conn_gaz= new doCommsgaz(listenergaz);
            Thread tgaz = new Thread(conn_gaz);
            tgaz.start();
            }

            ok.pole3.setText(wiadomosc);
            ok.pole2.setText(gaz);

          }
        } 
        catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            //System.out.println("IOException on socket listen: " + ioe);
            ioe.printStackTrace();
          }

    }

}

    class doComms implements Runnable {
        private Socket server;
        private ServerSocket listener;
        private String line,input;

        doComms(ServerSocket listener) {
            this.listener=listener;
          }

        public void run () {

          input="";

          try {

              Socket server;
              server = listener.accept();
            // Get input from the client
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream (server.getInputStream());
            //PrintStream out = new PrintStream(server.getOutputStream());

            Okno.wiadomosc = in.readUTF();

            server.close();
            Okno.skrecam=0;
          } catch (IOException ioe) {
            //System.out.println("IOException on socket listen: " + ioe);
            ioe.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
    }

    class doCommsgaz implements Runnable {
        private Socket server;
        private ServerSocket listener;
        private String line,input;

        doCommsgaz(ServerSocket listener) {
            this.listener=listener;
          }

        public void run () {

          input="";

          try {

              Socket server;
              server = listener.accept();
            // Get input from the client
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream (server.getInputStream());
            //PrintStream out = new PrintStream(server.getOutputStream());

            Okno.gaz = in.readUTF();

            server.close();
            Okno.gazuje=0;
          } catch (IOException ioe) {
            //System.out.println("IOException on socket listen: " + ioe);
            ioe.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
    }

class Window extends JFrame {
    private JButton ustaw;
    public JTextField pole1;
    public JTextField pole2;
    public JTextField pole3;
    Window()
    {
        setSize(300,200);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(4,1)); 
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setLayout(new FlowLayout(1));
        getContentPane().add(panel1);
        pole1 = new JTextField(15);
        panel1.add(pole1);
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setLayout(new FlowLayout(1));
        getContentPane().add(panel2);
        pole2 = new JTextField(15);
        panel2.add(pole2);
        JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
        panel3.setLayout(new FlowLayout(1));
        getContentPane().add(panel3);
        pole3 = new JTextField(15);
        panel3.add(pole3);
        JPanel panel4 = new JPanel();
        panel4.setLayout(new FlowLayout(1));
        getContentPane().add(panel4);
        ustaw = new JButton("Ustaw");
        panel4.add(ustaw);
        //action button handler
        ustaw.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent zdarz){
            try{
            }
            catch(Exception wyjatek){}
            pole1.setText("costam");
        }
    });
    }
}
```

Once again, sorry for the non optimized, and hard-to-read code. But please, if someone knows what would be better, please respond.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The client socket code should go into an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).  Google has a good into to it [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html).  This will not speed anything up but it will stop your app from freezing.  You can put in a "Processing" message while displaying a progress dialog to let the user know that something is happening.

Comment: thanks for Your attention! sure I will check and use AsyncTask, as it seems to be pretty useful. But, does it really solve my problem? I mean, there's no rocket science - i've got few data, need to send it, and I want it to be sent real-time with no jams, but with my skills i can't.